# Reasoning with _raw and normal data in Gatsby, GraphQL and Sanity

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, sanity

I've just started using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) with the [Sanity](https://www.sanity.io/) headless CMS.

For the most part it's pretty straight forward; but knowing best practises for querying the data through GraphQL is still bothering me. How I'm doing it currently is just frantically clicking through my CMS structure in the GraphQL playground and finding what I want. This works but the lack of uniformity in this approach is making me uneasy.

For example, if I want a hero image that's in the CMS somewhere, i'll need to do something like:

```
query SomePageQuery($id: String) {
  sanitySomePage(id: { eq: $id }) {
    id
    heroImage {
      asset {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1500) {
          ...GatsbySanityImageFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I want some [PortableText](https://github.com/portabletext/portabletext) block then I need to query the corresponding `_raw` field of whatever type. So, if my type was `introText`, Gatsby also provides a `_rawIntroText`. I'm only able to get the full PortableText from this `_raw` version of the data. Like this:

```
query SomePageQuery($id: String) {
  sanitySomePage(id: { eq: $id }) {
    id
    _rawIntroText
  }
}
```

It seems that, for some data you can use `[Type]`, and sometimes you ***have*** to use `_raw[Type]`.

There's not a great deal of documentation as to *why* this is the case. And I'm not sure if this is enforced via Sanity or Gatsby.

My question I guess would be, why does `_raw[Anything]` exist in the Gatsby and/or Sanity world, and how do people decide on which to use (other than just trial and error within the GraphQL playground and at runtime)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is coming from the gatsby-source-sanity plugin that Sanity built and maintains. Hopefully someone from Sanity can provide more context, but effectively the `_raw[FieldName]` entries return the original JSON data for the field. The unprefixed field (e.g. `fieldName`) is probably not what you want—it'll only contain bits of metadata about the data.

I tend to pull the `_raw[FieldName]` data and then just pass it straight into the `@sanity/block-content-to-react` component like so:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import SanityBlockContent from "@sanity/block-content-to-react"

export default ({ data: { page } }) => (
  <SanityBlockContent
    blocks={page.textContent}
    projectId={process.env.GATSBY_SANITY_PROJECT_ID}
    dataset={process.env.GATSBY_SANITY_DATASET}
  />
)

export const query = graphql`
  query SomePageQuery($id: String) {
    page: sanitySomePage(id: { eq: $id }) {
      textContent: _rawTextContent
    }
  }
`
```

Note that I'm using GraphQL aliasing to continue to refer to the field as `textContent` in my component rather than coupling the component to the specifics of this GraphQL schema.

You don't need to use Gatsby Image for Sanity images since they have their own image transformation pipeline anyways. Instead you can just fetch `asset { _id }` and then use `@sanity/client` like this to generate an image url:

```js
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client"
import sanityImageUrl from "@sanity/image-url"

const client = sanityClient({
  dataset: process.env.GATSBY_SANITY_DATASET,
  projectId: process.env.GATSBY_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  useCdn: true,
})

const builder = sanityImageUrl(client)

builder.image({ _id: "..." }).width(400).dpr(2).url()
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's how I'm currently dealing with the block content. So what I'm hearing is that anything Sanity related is being loaded into the `_raw` prefixed fields, and anything specific to Gatsby is in the other fields. For example, I'm using `gatsby-image`, which doesn't seem to work when I try and feed it `_raw` fields. So it sounds like I'm destined to think about where best to grab this data from on a case-by-case basis? The trick of aliasing is definitely useful as it will help me keep some consistency in the way my components consume the data.

Comment: The difference is that the `_raw` fields are typed as `JSON` in the GraphQL schema, and transformers like Gatsby Image are not going to operate on that node type. With Sanity, you really don't need Gatsby Image in your GraphQL queries anyways. You can use the `@sanity/client` package directly. I'll update with an example.

Comment: Thanks for the `@sanity/image-url` example, but I was doing that before but we decided to go with the Netlify CDN for delivering the images for speed. Gatsby Image also seemed to have a few more features. Any other reason for using the Sanity implementation over the host server? Obviously the ease of staying within one ecosystem would be a plus.

Comment: Hmm, you'd still need to actually download all of your images as part of your build. Sanity's asset API uses Google Cloud CDN in front, so I don't know that you're going to have much improvement by using Netlify instead, especially once you consider the cache invalidations on each deploy.

Comment: To be clear, you can still use the Gatsby Image React component with Sanity image-url, you just build your own srcSet and hand it over. Personally I don't do that because the `fluid` and `fixed` approaches are less flexible, but ymmv. FWIW, the SanityAsset in your GraphQL nodes includes a low-res preview you can embed (base64) rather than having Gatsby re-generate it.

Comment: Ok, noted. Thanks for your help.